# Override only Get accessor

Tags: c#

I got an abstract class :

```
abstract class ClassBase
    {
        public abstract string Test { get; }
    }
```

I want to derive it and by the way add a set accesor

```
 class ClassDerive : ClassBase
    {
        string _s;

        public override string Test
        {
            get { return _s; }
            set { _s = value; }
        }
    }
```

I can't do that because i may not override set

```
 class ClassDerive2 : ClassBase
    {
        string _s;

        public string Test
        {
            override get { return _s; }
            set { _s = value; }
        }
    }
```

Syntax error

```
class ClassDerive3 : ClassBase
{
    string _s;

    public override string ClassBase.Test
    {
        get { return _s; }
    }

    public string Test
    {
        set { _s = value; }
    }
}
```

Syntax error

Any Idea ???

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If at first you have defined a read-only property in a type, you can't later change it to a read/write property in a derived class. That's simply how .NET works, and can't be changed.

If, on the other hand, you define an *interface* with a read-only property, you can later implement that interface in a class with a writable property.

If you'd like to share what you are trying to achieve, perhaps we can come up with a design that works and can compile :)

Comment: Hello, 
thx for the answer. I does not have a"real" problem. because in my design, i can add the set accesor in the base class.

But I was just wondering...

Comment: Okay. Usually, it turns out that you don't really need this capability anyway, since you can often design yourself out of any such predicament. Not that I'm saying that you never need it, but most often you don't...

Answer (score 6):

You cannot do *exactly* what you want to do but here is a workaround:

```
abstract class ClassBase
{
    public abstract String Test { get; }
}

class ClassDerive : ClassBase
{
    string _s;

    public override string Test
    {
        get { return _s; }
    }

    public void SetTest(String test)
    {
        this._s = test;
    }
}
```

This will make `Test` only settable in `ClassDerived` via the public `SetTest` method.  I know this is not as clean as using the property's setter but it is about as good as it's going to get.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
    abstract class ClassBase
    {
        public abstract string Test { get; }
    }

    class ClassDerive : ClassBase
    {
        string _s;
        protected void setTest(string s)
        {
            _s = s;
        }

        public override string Test
        {
            get { return _s; }
        }
    }

    class ClassDerive2 : ClassDerive
    {
        public new string Test
        {
            get { return base.Test; }
            set { setTest(value); }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cd2 = new ClassDerive2();
            cd2.Test = "asdf";
            Console.WriteLine(cd2.Test);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using the 'new' keyword for the accessor is indeed described in the msdn documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287786(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

My first thought was also to implement it as an interface.  If this fits in with your design, the following code will work:

```
public interface TestInterface
{
   string TestProperty { get; }
}

public class TestClass : TestInterface
{
   public string TestProperty
   {
      get { return "test"; }
      set { string t = value; }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No you cant, sorry. It is by design, so it's the law.